# Xcode8 submission error - how to find out what exactly requires specific permissions on iOS10

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, xcode8

When trying to submit the app, I get the following error:

> This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage
>   description. The app's Info.plist must contain an
>   NSCalendarsUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the
>   user how the app uses this data.

I know I could just add a description to make the new validator happy, but my app doesn't use the user calendar, so I'd rather eliminate the dependency that uses it, if possible. I wasn't able to figure out how do I find out which dependency actually uses the calendar, how do check this?

My project has the following dependencies:

```
pod 'SnapKit', '0.22.0'
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.5'
pod "AFNetworking", '~> 3.1'
pod 'SDWebImage'      
pod 'TTTAttributedLabel'
pod 'Masonry'
pod 'CocoaLumberjack/Swift', '2.3'
pod 'SZTextView'
pod 'HockeySDK', :subspecs => ['CrashOnlyLib']
pod 'GoogleMaps'
pod 'BugfenderSDK'
pod 'AppsFlyerFramework', '4.5.0'
pod 'CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout'
pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'CRToast', '~> 0.0.7'
pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
pod 'UIColor_Hex_Swift', :git => 'https://github.com/yeahdongcn/UIColor-Hex-Swift.git', :tag => '2.3'
```

And the linked frameworks:

[image: List of linked frameworks]

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39440016/itunes-connect-upload-rejected-with-invalid-binary-because-of-missing-nscalendar  . See one of comment given by rmaddy for finding which method is accessing private information by searching within your code

Comment: @AmodGokhale thanks, but I have tried that already, I don't have such calls in my workspace.

Comment: it's better to open a technical ticket with apple and let them point out which method is requesting for permission instead of just guessing it's admob.

Comment: @AmodGokhale Fair point, but I thought there might already be a way to figure this out without asking Apple, which I hoped would be quicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have contacted Apple, and they actually have a nice list of all the APIs and the permissions that they require. You can find it [here (Technical Q&A QA1937)](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1937/_index.html).

Answer (score 0):

i think it's helpful for information for you.

I can see in Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK file that it references the libraries associated with these permissions. and also Google's frameworks for AdMob and GoogleSignIn installs firebase automatically which uses such permissions even though the app never does. After I defined `NSCameraUsageDescription` in the info.plist, it let me submit without problem hoping that the app won't prompt the user ever so they won't see the text either.

Many Advertising SDKs, such as AdMob, have EventKit as a required framework.
Until then you can workaround by adding `NSCalendarsUsageDescription` to your info.plist. I also had to do the same with `NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription`

**Edit: Very important to also add the NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription one as well see: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/ios/UmeVUDrcDaw**

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it does not answer my question.