# iOS 10 photo access error

Tags: ios, objective-c, privacy, photosframework

I am getting this error when submiting to Apple store.

> Important: To protect user privacy, an iOS app linked on or after iOS
>   10.0, and which accesses the user’s photo library,   must statically declare the intent to do so. Include the
>   NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key in your app’s Info.plist   file and
>   provide a purpose string for this key. If your app attempts to access
>   the user’s photo library without a   corresponding purpose string,
>   your app exits.

The thing is I don't use the photo lib. How can I find out what is using this? It could be a pod from cocoa pods.

Comment: One suggestion: why not just do what they say? Add the Info.plist key.

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39383289/ios-10-gm-release-error-when-submitting-apps-this-app-attempts-to-access-privac will help.